# Whitelisting for Article schema

Tags: google-schemas

what's the procedure to get whitelisted for using https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/article schema?

your published form is only working for actions and as I would like to mostly use e-mail notifications for new news (for categories user specificly requests after double opting in) i'm wondering how this is done.

also with regard to your article schema, do you plan to make it compatible with article schema (https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/articles) .. both links claim to be schema.org compatible.

Thank you,

Primoz

Answer (score 0):

You will have to submit a [form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1PA-vjjk3yJF7MLPOVKbIz3MBfhyma2obS8NIZ0JYx8I/viewform?pli=1) and provide a email with the schema you're trying to implement. I've noticed the form doesn't include "article" in the selection. I would just state in the description that you're interested in article schemas.

Be sure to check out their guidelines:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google?hl=en#email_sender_quality_guidelines

For your last question, on the bottom of the [Article documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/article) it states *"Note: Some of the schemas used by Google are still going through the standardization process of schema.org, and therefore, may change in the future."*

You can also refer to: https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/schema-org-proposals